# woocommerce re-add "add to cart" button for single post upsell item

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce

I need help!

I removed the "add to cart" button from my main store page because "see items" makes more sense in this case.

here is the code I added to my child functions.php theme:

`

```
function remove_loop_button(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    $text = _( 'See Items');
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addto_cart_button">See Items</a>';
}
```

`
It swaps out the button correctly on the main shop page but in the single post, the upsell also shows "see items" when I want it to say "add to cart" ... I have tried everything.

UPDATE: solved i think? it works, anyway :-)

// add add to cart back to upsell

```
'    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',   'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_upsells', 15 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_output_upsells' ) ) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_output_upsells' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_output_upsells() {
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'replace_add_to_cart');
        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    }
   }    
} '
```