# Woocommerce add to cart event and upsell page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to have an additional page to upsell other products (something like [this](https://www.hearingaidtv.com/specialoffers.asp)) after add to cart button click on a product page?

I have checked few plugins but all of them are provide upsell functionality on the same page as main product (as a sidebar or extra footer) but not as extra step in the checkout funnel.

Also I saw [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210590/woocommerce-re-add-add-to-cart-button-for-single-post-upsell-item) problem but in my case I'm looking to have it across single product as well.

Edit.
I have try to use redirect to a custom page on "Add to Cart" event

```
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

but I have no idea how to prevent that filter to be triggered on that custom page "Add to cart" buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it must be wrapped by a statement checking against page ID using `get_the_ID()` function to prevent "Add to cat" redirect on a custom page.